# How to add catalog item from external source?

Tags: servicenow

I have created one catalogs "Job Deployment" in service now.Under Job Deployment I have created two Categories A and B.

I am trying to list catalog item under those categories from external script.

Comment: Please add some information on what you have already tried. If possible provide some code and more details.

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer Thanks for the reply.I have updated my question with some info. Actually I am very new to service now so don't know much .Whatever I have done till now it was just a UI work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're wondering why you're not getting any responses, it's because your english is so poor that nobody can understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience .I have updated my question.And I will try to improve my English.